# Criando urls htaccess automático limitando quantidade mínima de caracteres

Tags: php, htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /nomes.php?nome=$1&matricula=$2
```

Eu preciso determinar que o redirecionamento de $nome tenha no mínimo três caracteres.

Eu fiz algo assim:

```
    $nome = @$_POST['nome'].@$_GET['nome'];

    if( strlen( $nome ) < 3){
    echo "Erro!";
    exit();
}
```

Resolveu meu problema. Como eu modifico isso para também adicionar que: Se o $nome não estiver no banco de dados ele também retornar erro?

A checagem seria com o:

```
$arrayReturn['nome']
```

Comment: A variável `$nome` está com o valor correto? De um `var_dump` e verifica

Comment: Realmente, a resposta era NULL. Adicionei: $nome = @$_POST['nome'].@$_GET['nome']; e funcionou.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam, fiz uma modificação na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confira a resposta de

```
var_dump ($nome)
var_dump ($arrayReturn['nome'])
```

E a lógica é a mesma

```
if( $nome <> $arrayReturn['nome']){
        echo "Erro!";
        exit();
    }
```

Se entendi bem, o retorno da $arrayReturn['nome'] deve ser algo como: Stack Overflow e o $nome stack-overflow

Estou certo? Adicione então a função:

```
<?php
/***
 * Função para remover acentos de uma string
 *
 * @autor Thiago Belem <contato@thiagobelem.net>
 */
function removeAcentos($string, $slug = false) {
  $string = strtolower($string);
  // Código ASCII das vogais
  $ascii['a'] = range(224, 230);
  $ascii['e'] = range(232, 235);
  $ascii['i'] = range(236, 239);
  $ascii['o'] = array_merge(range(242, 246), array(240, 248));
  $ascii['u'] = range(249, 252);
  // Código ASCII dos outros caracteres
  $ascii['b'] = array(223);
  $ascii['c'] = array(231);
  $ascii['d'] = array(208);
  $ascii['n'] = array(241);
  $ascii['y'] = array(253, 255);
  foreach ($ascii as $key=>$item) {
    $acentos = '';
    foreach ($item AS $codigo) $acentos .= chr($codigo);
    $troca[$key] = '/['.$acentos.']/i';
  }
  $string = preg_replace(array_values($troca), array_keys($troca), $string);
  // Slug?
  if ($slug) {
    // Troca tudo que não for letra ou número por um caractere ($slug)
    $string = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', $slug, $string);
    // Tira os caracteres ($slug) repetidos
    $string = preg_replace('/' . $slug . '{2,}/i', $slug, $string);
    $string = trim($string, $slug);
  }
  return $string;
}
```

E altere para:

```
if( $nome <> str_replace(" ","-",removerosAcentos($arrayReturn['nome'])) ){
        echo "Erro!";
        exit();
    }
```